# Is it possible to define an order relation on any infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to show that if and only if $A$ is infinite then there exists a bijection from a proper subset $(\subset$ and not $\subseteq )$ B to A $(\exists f: B \rightarrow A, bijective)$. For the first implication I have thought about defining a family. $(a_i)_{i\in A}$. Let $x\in A$, define $B:=A/\{x\}$,

set

$a_1 = g:\{x\}\rightarrow B,g(x)=y\in B$

$a_{n+1}= g':Im(a_n) \rightarrow B,g'(x)=y'\in B:y' \notin\bigcup_{i\leq n}Im(a_i)$

That would be the injective map from $A$ to $B$, while the other injective map would just be the identity[Thereby proving it is bijective]. But I have assumed that there is a 'starting element' 1 and a orderelation '$\leq$'. Is it possible to somehow just choose an element $z\in A$ and define it as the starting element and likewise choose a 2,3,4 … and so on to establish an order relation? But wouldn't that also mean that for example $A=\mathbb{R}$ would be bijective to $\mathbb{N}$? Like I have said in the title I would like to know if it is possible to create an orderrelation without breaking the general rules.

Thank you.

Comment: Apart from being mangled, the claim in your first sentence is false. Indeed, there's a bijection from $\{0\}$ to $\{0\}$, but $\{0\}$ clearly isn't infinite, there is no bijection from any subset of the reals to the powerset of the reals. As for your question: yes, you can put an order relation on any set. Without the axiom of choice, though, you can't put a well-order (that is: an order relation that has a "starting element") on arbitrary sets. To answer the rest of your confusion: a set being well-ordered does not mean that it is countable, no.

Comment: Sorry my English is not so good but B must be a real subset of B, i.e. $B\subseteq A,B\neq A$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will write then by the Axiom of Choice there exists such an order and thus $(a_i)_{i\in A}$ is injective

Comment: The first sentence is false.

Comment: I believe that by "real subset" you mean "*proper* subset."

Comment: @user3482749 The fact that every set can be linearly ordered depends on the axiom of choice, though it''s weaker than the full axiom of choice.